# How to approach changes in backend for Apple Push Notifications?

Tags: ios, localization, apple-push-notifications, localizable.strings

I am using APN in my app and I was wondering - what if I add a new type of notification and send new *STRING_KEY* in the JSON - I update my app but, let's assume that 30% of my user base doesn't update immediately. Logically - they will receive the push notification without the "new type" included and therefore instead of:

**Localized.strings:**

`"STRING_KEY" = "This is the new string.";`

displaying the text above, the notification will be displayed as "STRING_KEY".

Is there any best-practice approach, or "conditional string", or pre-handle method for displaying the message in push notification?

Comment: The way I've handled this is to version the APIs my apps use to connect to my servers. Then customise the APNS message for the app based on the API version the app is using. Not sure if it's best practice but it works...